# wait() & in partent loop linux

Tags: c, linux, wait

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
   int x,y,status, i;
   int cnt = 0;
   int flag = 0;
   char buf[50];
   char str[50];
   char * argv[10];
   char * ptr;


   for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    printf("$");
    gets(buf);
    strcpy(str, buf);

    ptr = strtok(buf, " ");

    while(ptr != NULL){
      argv[cnt] = ptr;
      cnt++;
      ptr = strtok(NULL," ");
    }



    if(!strcmp(argv[cnt-1], "&")) {
      argv[cnt-1] = 0;
      flag = 1;
    }
    else {
        argv[cnt] = 0;
    }



    if(!strcmp(argv[0],"exit")) exit(0);

    x=fork();

    if (x==0){
        sleep(1);
        printf("I am child to execute %s\n", str);
        y=execve(argv[0], argv, 0);

        if (y<0){
           perror("exec failed");
           exit(1);
        }

    }
    else {
      if(flag == 0) { 
          wait(&status); 
      }
    }


    flag = 0;
    cnt = 0;
   }
}
```

I want to exec background with '&'

like real linux shell

so I divied

```
   else {
      if(flag == 0) { 
          wait(&status); 
      }
    }
```

like this

so it works well

if I enter /bin/ls (without &)
prompt $ is placed after /bin/ls

and if I enter /bin/ls & (with &)
then prompt $ is placed before /bin/ls

but rewrite /bin/ls (without &) like first time I entered
then prompt $ is placed before /bin/ls

why?

```
===============

$/bin/ls
I am child to execute /bin/ls
ch f1 f2 shell shell.c t t.c test test.c testfile

$/bin/ls &
$I am child to execute /bin/ls &
ch f1 f2 ch f1 f2 shell shell.c t t.c test test.c testfile

$/bin/ls
$I am child to execute /bin/ls
ch f1 f2 shell shell.c t t.c test test.c testfile

================
Is it right?
```

Comment: I cannot read the screen shot. Please post text as text.

Comment: Put a `putc('$');` after the call to `wait()`.

Comment: $/bin/ls
I am child to execute /bin/ls
ch f1 f2 shell shell.c t t.c test test.c testfile
$

$/bin/ls &
$I am child to execute /bin/ls &
ch f1 f2 shell shell.c t t.c test test.c testfile


$/bin/ls
$I am child to execute /bin/ls
ch f1 f2 shell shell.c t t.c test test.c testfile

===================

Comment: You can update your question using the 'edit'-button right below it.

Comment: Updating/extending a question in comments does not make much sense. It gets to messy.

Comment: Also use of `gets` is deprecated. use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: @alk can you see pictures??

Comment: I cannot read/parse screen shots.

Comment: Please add the information from your comments to the question itself. Show textual information as text. While StackOverflow by far does not expect perfect English, please stay away from the language level involving "wanna".

Comment: big ? what's mean

Comment: What alk is trying to tell you is to edit your question and show text as text, not as picture of text. Some people simply refuse looking at pictures of text.

Comment: Much better! :-)

Comment: @alk I modified it

Comment: @alk putc not works, parents does not wait child...

Comment: Ah, I see. You could inside the child fork another child, the grandchild, this then would do the exec, and the child (the 1st, not the grandchild, but its parent) would wait for its child (the grandchild) and print the `$` ... :-)

Comment: @alk uhmmm I think my code makes just one child in one loop. so I think it doesn't make grandchild. isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say '$' behavior is expected.

I don't even know how does this code compile. You can't use `void main(){` (at least while using gcc). Valid form would be `int main() {`. Also, you can simplify your code a lot:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() { /*Changed void main()*/
   int x, y, status, i, cnt=0, flag=0; /*Squashed declarations*/
   char buf[50]; /*removed str*/
   char * argv[10], * ptr;
   for(i=0; i<10; i++){
      putchar('$'); /*printf() is overkill. Also, watch out for this!*/
      fgets(buf, 49, stdin); /*49 (null terminator), gets --> fgets*/
      /*strcpy(str, buf); <-- why?*/
      ptr = strtok(buf, " ");
      while(ptr != NULL) {
          argv[cnt++] = ptr;
          ptr = strtok(NULL," ");
      }
      if(!strcmp(argv[cnt-1], "&")) {
          argv[cnt-1] = 0;
          flag = 1;
      } else {
          argv[cnt] = 0;
      }
      if(!strcmp(argv[0],"exit"))
          return 0;
      x=fork();
      if (!x) {
          sleep(1);
          y=execve(argv[0], argv, 0);

          if (y<0) {
              perror("execve failed");
              return 1;
          }

      } else {
          if(!flag) { 
              wait(&status); 
          }
      }
      flag = 0;
      cnt = 0;
   }
}
```

You are creating children, and echoing '$' in every case - that makes '$' show up.

After, `fork()`, '$' is getting displayed once again, even when you are executing process.

Comment: thank you but, parent doesn't wait child after later enter &

Comment: first :  /bin/ls => parent wait child

Comment: second : /bin/ls & => parent doesn't wait child

Comment: third : /bin/ls => parent doesn't wait child

Comment: I expected to see third parent wait child